# Buttons na versão mobile não funcionam

Tags: javascript, mobile

Bom dia pessoal, tenho um site finalizado, está funcinando perfeitamente no desktop, porém no modo mobile, todos os botões não funcionam, o menu lateral porém está perfeito, só os botões das páginas que nao funcionam. Estou usando esses comando para os botões:

```
<a href="research.jsp" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">MORE</a>
```

CSS:

```
btn-primary {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3314a8;
  border-color: #250d7e;
}
.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #eb3865;
  border-color: #df0038;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease;
  -o-transition: 0.3s all ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}
.btn-primary:active {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Estás a usar alguma biblioteca ou código JavaScript? Senão não vejo razão para essa ancora não funcionar...

Comment: @Sergio Sim, jquery.flexslider-min.js e jquery-min.js

Comment: Ok, e tens algum código teu ou da aplicação que interfere com esses links?

Comment: Não não, tudo parece estar certo..